# One word describing smart, funny and awesome

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

I am trying to search for a single word that describes someone being smart funny and awesome?

Comment: The adjective [**charismatic**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/charismatic) goes in that direction, but not all the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you'll find a single word.

"Witty" could work for "smart" and "funny". But don't think you could combine "awesome" in there.

Comment: I suppose it depends on whether the OP means the original, old-fashioned meaning of 'awesome', or its current milder one.